# Match statements with conditionals

Tags: scala

I want to do something like:

```
myVar match{
   case 0 => 1
   case (myVar > 9) => 10
   case _ => _
}
```

Is there a way to do this with match statements in scala?

Comment: Why was the correct answer mark taken away, may I ask?

Comment: It's a common courtesy to at least reply when someone's asking you something.

Comment: That was 22 hours ago. It must have been an accident. You should have probably given me a little more than 8 hours before you get on my case about common courtesy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myVar match {
  case 0 => 1
  case n if n > 9 => 10
  case n => n
}
```

Comment: I think it is useful to mention, that this is called a `guard`.